# Setting liveserver port when running tests in django

Tags: django, selenium, docker, django-testing, django-tests

I am using django for a webapp and I'm using docker to deploy it. I need to test it in the container with selenium. I'm using selenium grid for testing. In order to connect with the liveserver on the docker, i need to port forward a specific port, but as far as i read in the django docs, LiveServerTestCase uses port 0, which means random port every time i run the tests. Since --liveserver options is deprecated, is there any other way to set the port of the test server or a smarter way to test it with selenium ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If anyone is wondering this is how I did it:
Override method setUpClass, which starts the thread on which the server run

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    cls.host = "example.com" # or ip
    cls.port = 12345
    super(ExampleTestCase, cls).setUpClass()
```

Comment: You method works (thanks!), but your code is misleading: You're writing a class method, so you get the class (and not an instance of that class) which is called `cls` by convention.

Answer (score 4):

All the previous answers work well, but the most succinct way to set the port is as follows:

```
class MyTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):
    port = 12345
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Django 1.11 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.11/#liveservertestcase-binds-to-port-zero) you should set the `port` attribute on the `LiveServerTestCase`:

> If you need to bind `LiveServerTestCase` to a specific port, use the `port` attribute added in Django 1.11.2.